# how to get data from a client side database in asp.net web application?

Tags: asp.net

How to get data from a client side database in asp.net web application?
I want to build a web application in Visual Studio 2010 where the web application takes data from the user's database which is stored on user's computer and process this data and then copy this data to the web application's database. 
Is this possible?

Comment: In that case a server-side web application does not make any sense at all.

Comment: ohk.. but I want to deploy this application then?